# Comparing to Boolean / boolean in javascript

Tags: javascript, boolean

Should you use == or === to compare with Boolean / boolean values in js?
Problem is:

```
> true == new Boolean(true)
< true
> true === new Boolean(true)
< false
```

same goes for String:

```
> 'foo' == new String('foo')
< true
> 'foo' === new String('foo')
< false
```

I understand that this is happening because String and Boolean are objects whereas true, false and 'string' are literals.

```
function foo(bar){
  /* if statement here{ 
    I want the code between these two lines to execute when and only when foo is true,
    or new Boolean(true), which operator to use?
  } */
```

}

Comment: There's no good reason to ever use `new Boolean()`. These objects don't act like booleans. `new Boolean(false)` is truthy.

Comment: In addition to @Barmar, there is very few circumstances where `x == true` is needed. If you are checking for truthiness, `x` suffices; if you want to see if it's exactly `true`, you need to write `x === true`.

Comment: @Amadan My point is that `x` doesn't work at all if you use `new Boolean`, since both `new Boolean(true)` and `new Boolean(false)` are truthy.

Comment: @Barmar: I was agreeing with you. I guess I wasn't clear. 1) Don't use `Boolean`, 2) if you use primitive boolean, don't use `x == true`.

Comment: @p.s.w.g `typeof bar === "boolean" && bar` isn't it the same as `bar === true` ??

Comment: @rabbit.aaron For some reason I was thinking `typeof new Boolean(true)` → `"boolean"`, but it doesn't. I supposed you're right. I retract my previous comment.

Comment: @Barmar I would never use `Boolean`, but I have no control of what passed into my function, right? Say if I'm writing a library, should I check for `Boolean` type?

Comment: If someone gives you a wrapped boolean when you're expecting an ordinary boolean, that's a bug in the caller. You don't have to do anything. They'll get the same behavior from any other library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try using the [`valueOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf) method to get the underlying value of a wrapped Boolean:

```
function isTrue(b) { 
   return b.valueOf() === true; 
}

isTrue(true);                      // true
isTrue(new Boolean(true));         // true
isTrue(false);                     // false
isTrue(new Boolean(false));        // false
isTrue("true");                    // false
```

However, I should note that it's possible to override this function for custom types or even for built-in types, for example:

```
Boolean.prototype.valueOf = function () { return true; }; 
isTrue(false);                     // true
```

Also note, this simple example doesn't handle `null` or `undefined` values.

In general though, I wouldn't use this kind of method for general purpose parameter validation in a library. I think it's fairly safe to assume that if a user passes in a `new Boolean(true)` they probably have a specific reason for doing so (or as [*Barmar*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25735257/comparing-to-boolean-boolean-in-javascript#comment40237660_25735257) says, it's a bug in their code).

Comment: Your `Number.p.valueOf` example is meaningless, because 123 is truthy to begin with. I suggested an edit to fix that nit.

Comment: @impinball It's not meaningless. Without overriding the method, `isTrue(123)` → `false`. Remember, this method doesn't test if a `b` is truthy, it tests if its primitive value exactly equals `true`.

Comment: @pswg I still left my edit because it also mentions truthiness/falsiness, which can also come into play.

Comment: @impinball Thanks, I've edited to provide an even more clear example of how this method can be subverted.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, if you know you're dealing with the object variants, then it is better, in both performance and readability's sake, to stick with `.valueOf() === some_boolean` than using non-strict equals. Example:

```
var b = new Boolean(true);
b.valueOf() === true; // true
```

It is typically better to avoid Boolean objects without a specific reason, because it leads to bugs very quickly because of that confusion. It also results in leaner, faster code when it matters.

```
var b = new Boolean(foo);

// ...

if (!b) {
  // This always executes, leading to some impossibly hidden bugs.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this solution.

```
function typeOf(obj) {
  return Object.prototype.toString.call(obj).slice(8, -1);
}

function foo(bar){
  if((typeOf(bar) === 'Boolean' && bar.valueOf() === true) || bar === true){
     // is this perfect though ?
  }
}



> Object.prototype.toString.call(true)
< "[object Boolean]"
> Object.prototype.toString.call(false)
< "[object Boolean]"
> Object.prototype.toString.call(Boolean(true))
< "[object Boolean]"
> Object.prototype.toString.call(Boolean(false))
< "[object Boolean]"
> Object.prototype.toString.call(new Boolean(true))
< "[object Boolean]"
> Object.prototype.toString.call(new Boolean(false))
< "[object Boolean]"
> Object.prototype.toString.call(undefined)
< "[object Undefined]"
> Object.prototype.toString.call(null)
< "[object Null]"
> Object.prototype.toString.call(1)
< "[object Number]"
```

Comment: I just realize I could have just do `bar.valueOf() === true`.